# How to add an image before section title

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I want to modify the section command to make it look like this:

[image]

I wrote a tikz code for the decorated section number but I still don't know how to integrate my code in the `\section` command:

```
\newcommand*\numb{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,rounded corners,top color=black!80!gray!20, bottom color=black!80,text=white]{ \huge 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option, using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package and a variation of your  `\numb` command:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\numb[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1.4ex]
\node[
  rectangle,
  rounded corners=2pt,
  top color=black!15,
  bottom color=black!90,
  text=white,
  inner ysep=0pt,
  text height=3ex,
  text depth=0.45ex]
  {\parbox{0.7cm}{\raggedleft\huge#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\numb{\thesection}}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section} 
\section{Another test section} 
\section*{An unnumbered section} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

A slightly different solution also with titlesec, so that the section number be on the baseline:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsproc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsproc

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\newcommand*\numb[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [rectangle,rounded corners,top color=black!80!gray!20, bottom color=black!  80,text=white]{ \huge #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\bfseries\large}{\raisebox{-5.4pt}{\numb{\arabic{section}}}}{0.4em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Fonctions homlomorphes}\label{sec:prelim}
 Première section

\section{Another section}
Voir Section~\ref{sec:prelim}.

\end{document}
```

[image]