# Custom subsection title with image

Tags: graphics, sectioning, titles

I would love to use custom subsection title with image in my TeX project, can anyone help me how to do it? I don't need it exactly the same just the layout is important. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Are you aware of the `titlesec` package?

Comment: thank you, no I have very little experience with TeX unfortunately I have to use it for my project. So you suggest me to learn `titlesec` package and with it I will be able to produce this title?

Comment: It was more the question if you are aware of it. I guess you could more or less use e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157170/121799) as a basis for a solution. And if you have problems, you have a code that you could use for a question here. (Usually questions involve some code that shows what you have tried.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `titlesec` is the way to go. If you want to keep the subsection number and title, try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\includegraphics{app.png}\hspace{0.5em}\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{First section} 
\subsection{First Subsection}
\end{document}
```

where `app.png` is the image of your app (if this image is too large, use the `width=` or `scale=` option of `\includegraphics`):

[image: outupt]

If you want to remove the subsection number from the title, remove `\hspace{0.5em}\thesubsection` from the `\titleformat` command, while if you want to remove the subsection title as well, load the titlesec package with the `explicit` option:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\includegraphics{app.png}}{0.5em}{}
```

And/or

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} % No subsection title unless explicitly included in \titleformat command
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\includegraphics{app.png}\hspace{0.5em}\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}
```

Comparison:

[image: output2]

And/or

[image: output2]

Similar could of course be done for the `\section` command.

Extra (see comments): You can add your own subection (or section) command to use a different image for different subsections. Using

```
\newcommand\mysubsection[3]{% #1: Image file (e.g. app.png), #2: Image scale, #3: Subsection title
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\includegraphics[scale=#2]{#1}\hspace{0.5em}\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}
 \subsection{#3}
}
```

The call

```
\mysubsection{example-image-a}{0.4}{Subsection title}
```

produces (following on from the previous examples)

[image: output4]

Comment: thanks! One important note: is it possible to add parameter to section title? To make app icon variable. Something like `\section{App name}{appicon}`

Comment: Yes, very easily - I'll add a small bit onto my answer for you