# How can I add Section Title and No. to a Table

Tags: tables, sectioning, books

I am preparing a template for writing Standard Policy and Procedure (SOP). I want to put the section title in a table cell and the number in another cell, as shown in the attached snapshot. My code is below:

[image]

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
        \usepackage{multirow}
        \usepackage{tabularx} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
        \usepackage{fancyhdr}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        
        
        \begin{document}
            
        \newcommand{\revno}{IR.01}
        \newcommand{\printdate}{01-Jan-23}
        \newcommand{\issuedate}{01-Jan-24}
        \newcommand{\co}{Saudia}
        \newcommand{\doctitle}{ADD TITLE}
        \newcommand{\owner}{Aircraft Sale}
        \newcommand{\revdate}{12-Jun-23}
         
         \chapter{Sale}
         \chapter{Buy}
         
         \section{My Section Title}
            
        \def\arraystretch{1.25}
        \begin{table}[h]
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|r|c|}
                \hline
                \multirow{4}{*}{LOGO} & \textbf{Document Title}    & \textbf{Policy No.} & 2.1 \\ \cline{2-4} 
                & \multirow{3}{*}{My Section Title} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \issuedate{} \\ \cline{3-4} 
                &                            & \textbf{Rev. Date}  & \revdate{}   \\ \cline{3-4} 
                &                            & \textbf{Ownership}  & \owner{}     \\ \hline
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
            
            
        \end{document}
```

Comment: If someone possesses a Standard Operating Procedure (SOP) template, I would greatly appreciate it if they could share it with me.

Comment: I have a feeling that what you looking for is a `document control`  front sheet for your OP. This would make more sense. Or do you want this to be as a footer on every page of the OP? Please expand on your question with how the document continues etc, and I can post some code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using a counter depending on `chapter`:

If you do not really want a `\section`, you can just define a number depending on `\chapter`:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,final,sfdefaults=false]{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\revno}{IR.01}
\newcommand{\printdate}{01-Jan-23}
\newcommand{\issuedate}{01-Jan-24}
\newcommand{\co}{Saudia}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{ADD TITLE}
\newcommand{\owner}{Aircraft Sale}
\newcommand{\revdate}{12-Jun-23}

\newcounter{mynum}\counterwithin{mynum}{chapter}
\newcommand*{\nextnum}{\refstepcounter{mynum}}

\chapter{Sale}
\chapter{Buy}

\nextnum
 
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{table}[h]% Does not really make sense.
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|r|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{LOGO} & \textbf{Document Title}    & \textbf{Policy No.} & \themynum \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multirow{3}{*}{The Title where I want it} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \issuedate{} \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Rev. Date}  & \revdate{}   \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Ownership}  & \owner{}     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

## Refering an existing section counter and title text:

If I'm wrong, and you want a section, you could use a `\label{…}` after `\section{…}` and then `\ref{…}` and `\nameref{…}` (last needs package `nameref`):

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\revno}{IR.01}
\newcommand{\printdate}{01-Jan-23}
\newcommand{\issuedate}{01-Jan-24}
\newcommand{\co}{Saudia}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{ADD TITLE}
\newcommand{\owner}{Aircraft Sale}
\newcommand{\revdate}{12-Jun-23}

 \chapter{Sale}
 \chapter{Buy}

 \section{My Section Title}\label{sec:mysectiontitle}

\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|r|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{LOGO} & \textbf{Document Title}    & \textbf{Policy No.} & \ref{sec:mysectiontitle} \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multirow{3}{*}{\nameref{sec:mysectiontitle}} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \issuedate{} \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Rev. Date}  & \revdate{}   \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Ownership}  & \owner{}     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

## Refering the current section number and the current section level title (for ToC or page header):

With using a KOMA-Script class, you could also use `\@currentheadentry` or `\@currenttocentry`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,final,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\revno}{IR.01}
\newcommand{\printdate}{01-Jan-23}
\newcommand{\issuedate}{01-Jan-24}
\newcommand{\co}{Saudia}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{ADD TITLE}
\newcommand{\owner}{Aircraft Sale}
\newcommand{\revdate}{12-Jun-23}

\chapter{Sale}
\chapter{Buy}
\section{My Section Title}
%\subsection{My Subsection Title}

 
\def\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|r|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{LOGO} & \textbf{Document Title}    & \textbf{Policy No.} & \thesection \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multirow{3}{*}{\csname @currenttocentry\endcsname} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \issuedate{} \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Rev. Date}  & \revdate{}   \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Ownership}  & \owner{}     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

But this is only a hack, because using `\@currenttocentry` does not really refer the section title, but the section title that would be added to the ToC. And it does not always show the section title. For example, if you'd activate the `\subsection` command in my example, it would show the sub-section title instead.

## Using a table as section title:

And if the table should be the section title, KOMA-Script would also support this:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix,oneside,final]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \def\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|r|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{LOGO} & \textbf{Document Title}    & \textbf{Policy No.} & #3 \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multirow{3}{*}{#4} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \issuedate{} \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Rev. Date}  & \revdate{}   \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Ownership}  & \owner{}     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  }%
  {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}%
}
\makeatother
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\revno}{IR.01}
\newcommand{\printdate}{01-Jan-23}
\newcommand{\issuedate}{01-Jan-24}
\newcommand{\co}{Saudia}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{ADD TITLE}
\newcommand{\owner}{Aircraft Sale}
\newcommand{\revdate}{12-Jun-23}

\chapter{Sale}
\chapter{Buy}

\section{My Section Title}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm sure, you could something similar using a standard class and package `titlesec` (see for example [How to add an image before section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/157164/277964) as entry point).

## Extending the section command by additional variables used for a table style section heading:

A very nice feature of the KOMA-Script classes is, that you can extend the optional argument of commands like `\section` to, e.g., set the dates and ownership:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,sfdefaults=false,chapterprefix,oneside,final,sfdefaults=false,headings=optiontotocandhead]{scrbook}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx} \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}{%
    \def\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|r|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{LOGO} & \textbf{Document Title}    & \textbf{Policy No.} & #3 \\ \cline{2-4} 
        & \multirow{3}{*}{#4} & \textbf{Issue Date} & \issuedate{} \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Rev. Date}  & \revdate{}   \\ \cline{3-4} 
        &                            & \textbf{Ownership}  & \owner{}     \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
  }%
  {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\revdate}{}
\newcommand*{\issuedate}{}
\newcommand*{\owner}{}

\AddtoDoHook{heading/preinit/section}{% Initialize the values to N.A. with
                                % every \section.
  \renewcommand*{\revdate}{N.A.}%
  \renewcommand*{\issuedate}{N.A.}%
  \renewcommand*{\owner}{N.A.}%
  \csname @gobble\endcsname
}

% New \section options
\FamilyStringKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{issuedate}{\issuedate}
\FamilyStringKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{revdate}{\revdate}
\FamilyStringKey[.section]{KOMAarg}{owner}{\owner}

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\revno}{IR.01}
\newcommand{\printdate}{01-Jan-23}
\newcommand{\co}{Saudia}

\chapter{Sale}
\chapter{Buy}

\section[issuedate=01-Jan-24,revdate=12-Jun-23,owner=Aircraft Sale]{My Section Title}
 
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before:

[image]

Comment: But still 2.1 My Section Title appears above the table. I want to remove it.

Comment: @OOzyPal See the first, the fourth, fifth and sixth example in my answer.

Comment: I liked this (Extending the section command by additional variables used for a table style section heading:) 
My question how can I do normal section without the table.

Comment: @OOzyPal If you need two different kinds of sections (which would be very uncommon), you can define an additional section command. But this would be another question and would also need more details. See, e.g., `\DeclareNewSectionCommand` in the KOMA-Script manual. But maybe another suggestion would be better, if you'd specify the problem detailed in a new question.